# Wordpress MySQL error when adding orders within WooCommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Within WooCommerce in my Wordpress site, I have tried to add an order manually within the admin section. When I add multiple products / shipping and click "recalculate", the list of products clears.

I checked my website error log and noticed the following error:

`` [16-Dec-2019 11:56:14 UTC] WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` (`order_item_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES ('3476', 'shipping_tax_amount', '0') made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->create_order, WC_Order->save, WC_Abstract_Order->save_items, WC_Data->save, WC_Data_Store->create, Abstract_WC_Order_Item_Type_Data_Store->create, WC_Order_Item_Tax_Data_Store->save_item_data, update_metadata, add_metadata ``

Any advice on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated. It also appears to stop orders being made from the front end of the site too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SINCE CREATE query says

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_item_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `order_item_id` (`order_item_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(32))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3220 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

the `meta_id` is what the error complains about. This is weird since that field is AUTO_INCREMENT and should have a numeric non-zero value.
my guess is you have tried to create that table without adding primary key to it correctly. (or the data was already broken during import which caused the key to be not possible to add.)

Make sure to remove any '0' `meta_key` rows.

then, please make sure your table has `meta_key` column the same way as in my CREATE statement (auto increment). Once it is, it will create the value for you and not create the error when trying to add a new row from the admin panel.